# image over text

Tags: html, css

Here I'm using 3 images , I need text on the 3rd image..
my code is:

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <img src="Images/img1.png" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;" />
    <img src="Images/img2.png" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left:450px;" />
    <img src="Images/img3.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left:720px;" />
    <div style="position:relative;top: 0px; left:720px;">
        Home<br />
        contact<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to use `z-index` property.

Comment: Could you be more specific, or post an example?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478621/html-css-displaying-text-over-an-img-tag 

refer above link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to put your text `div` in position `absolute` ? It's inside the `relative` `div`...

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <img src="Images/img1.png" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;" />
    <img src="Images/img2.png" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left:450px;" />
    <img src="Images/img3.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left:720px;" />
    <div style="position:absolute;top: 0px; left:720px;">
        Home<br />
        contact<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Basic change is insted of `relative` use `absolute` like this

```
<div style="position:absolute;top: 0px; left:720px;">
                            Home<br />
                            contact<br />
</div>
```

**Relative Positioning** - A relative positioned element is positioned relative to its normal position.

**Absolute Positioning**- An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static.

Check for more details : [CSS Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: z-index is a better solution, relative and absolute have different uses.

Comment: @gaynorvader - check documentation relative and absolute...there is no issue of z index

Comment: @gaynorvader - check my updates...than do downvote on answer...

Comment: I retract my downvote, it was there before your updates. I know there's no issue, but it's possible that relative needs to be used over absolute, such as responsive design.

Answer (score 1):

You should use position:absolute rather than position:relative in order to take the element out of flow. You will need to adjust the left and top attributes, however.